# ArcGIS javascript Cluster Layer not working on a map with UTM spatial reference

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, clustering

I use [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/layers_point_clustering.html) sample's clusterlayer module to create a cluster layer. problem is that when map spatial reference is UTM the cluster layer that I added to map does not work properly. the errors are  
`svg.js:43 Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN".
setShape @ svg.js:43
svg.js:49 Error: <text> attribute x: Expected length, "NaN".
setShape @ svg.js:49
svg.js:49 Error: <text> attribute y: Expected length, "NaN".`

But when the map's spatial reference is web mercator it works fine.
this is how i create my cluster layer:

```
var clusterLayer = new ClusterLayer({
  "spatialReference": map.spatialReference,
  "data": clusterData,
  "distance": 75,
  "id": "clusters",
  "labelColor": "#000000",
  "showSingles": true,
  "resolution": map.extent.getWidth() / map.width,
  "singleColor": pColor 
});
```

I should note that `clusterData` is created based on map's spatial reference (coordinates are in map's spatial reference)

this is how clusterData created in UTM mode:

```
                        var splitedWkt = pLayerData[i]["SHAPE_WKT"].split(' ');
                        var endPoint = {
                            "x": splitedWkt[3],
                            "y": splitedWkt[4]
                        };
                        clusterData.push({
                            "x": endPoint.x,
                            "y": endPoint.y, 
                            "attributes": {}
                        });
```

"SHAPE_WKT" is the feature's shape that i get directly from database. (Well Known Text).

And this is one of the objects in clusterData array:

```
{x:"565623.31040000",
 y:"3616457.34120000",
 attributes:{}
```

}

Comment: can you add code to show how `clusterData` was calculated?

Comment: The difference from example is that you use strings for x and y coordinates, not numbers. Try to use var endPoint = { x: parseFloat(splitedWkt[3]), y: parseFloat(splitedWkt[4]))

Comment: ok. that was it! It's so embarrassing for me! thank you very much. @r.pankevicius